# Convert virtual include to php include

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to do a template match for comments so that it looks for virtual include and convert it to php include:

```
<node>
<!--#include virtual="/abc/contacts.html" -->
<!-- some random comment -->
</node>
```

to

```
<node>
<?php include($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/abc/contacts.html"); ?>
<!-- some random comment -->
</node>
```

I'm trying to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()" >
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^[\s\S]*&lt;!">
<xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?php&nbsp;</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="." /> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&nbsp;?&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help to solve this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Vinit, Was my answer useful to you, or do you still have any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need XSLT 2.0 for this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "comment()[starts-with(normalize-space(),'#include virtual=')]">

  <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
   <xsl:text>include($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-after(normalize-space(),'#include virtual=')"/>
   <xsl:text>);</xsl:text>
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<node>
    <!--#include virtual="/abc/contacts.html" -->
    <!-- some random comment -->
</node>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<node>
    <?php include($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/abc/contacts.html");?>
    <!-- some random comment -->

</node>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**, template match patterns, the XPath functions **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)** and **[`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with)**, and of the **[`xsl:processing-instruction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Processing-Instructions)** XSLT instruction.